On The Existence of The Single-Valued Entropy *Function* Via Caratheodory's Adiabatic Inaccessibility
I am looking for an explanation why the impossible example  of a thermodynamic systemm see $^{[\mathbf 1]}$, or its obvious generalization that is to follow below, is not allowed by Caratheodory's mathematics and axiomatization of thermostatics.
Arens defines a specific 2-variable thermodynamic system $\mathfrak S$ using the plane polar coordinates $r,\phi$. Instead, I use a  somewhat more general and less objectionable 3-variable example based on Arens as follows. Let a torus be parametrized with coordinates as
$$\begin{align}
x(\theta, \phi) &=(R+r\cos\theta)\cos\phi\\y(\theta, \phi) &=(R+r\cos\theta)\sin\phi\\z(\theta, \phi) &=r\sin\theta 
\end{align}$$
Let $r<1$ and $R>2$. We define the isothermal surface of temperature $T$ of $\mathfrak S$ to be the toroidal surface $T=\frac{r}{1-r}$ with $0<r<1$, and define the isentropic surfaces of $\mathfrak S$ to be the planar cross sections at angle $\phi$ having entropy $\sigma = \phi +\sigma_0$ where $\sigma_0$ is an arbitrary constant. The circle $r=0$ and the outermost surface $r=1$ correspond to $T(0)=0$ and $T(1)=\infty$, resp., are to be excluded from the states of the system  $\mathfrak S$. Similarly, the poloidal angle representing the configuration variable of $\mathfrak S$ is confined to $0<\theta<2\pi$, and the angles $0,2\pi$ are excluded from the configuration so that $\phi$ is single-valued.
Now under this definition of the reversible adiabatic surfaces the associated entropy is not unique; on the contrary, it is allowed to increase or decrease by $2\pi$ as many times as $\phi$ runs around the polar ("vertical") axis. But unlike $\sigma$ that is not single-valued, its differential increment $d\sigma$ is still single-valued.
The heat form is $\tilde \beta(r, \phi, \theta)=T d\sigma$; its integral $\int_{\mathcal P}\tilde \beta $ represents the total absorbed heat over any quasistatic reversible path in the $r,\phi, \theta$ space. Now, according to Kelvin's axiom the total absorbed heat in any reversible isothermal cycle is zero.
Specifically, let $\mathcal C(T)$ denote a constant temperature loop on the surface of any $r>0$ toroid. Then $\oint_{\mathcal C}\tilde \beta=0$ if the loop does not encircle the polar axis and then the loop is a thermodynamic cycle. If, on the other hand, the isothermal loop $\mathcal C(T)$ encircles the polar axis, such as a toroidal circle does, then $\oint_{\mathcal C}\tilde \beta=T\oint_{\mathcal C} \sigma =2\pi T \ne 0$ and $\mathcal C$ is not a thermodynamical cycle because its entropy is not a unique function of its temperature $T$ and configuration parameter $\phi$.
Here we have two classes of isothermal loops, some are thermodynamic cycles but others are not. Any homotopically trivial isothermal loop would satisfy Kelvin's axiom but there is also a class of nontrivial loops that cannot be shrunk to a point, and the entropy is not single-valued.
At the same time, the isentropic surfaces do satisfy Caratheodory's adiabatic inacessibility axiom, that is in any neighborhood of any of the states there are states that cannot be reached via an adiabatic path no matter how close the states are. In fact, from any state only those points are accessible by adiabatic (isentropic) means that are on the same adiabatic surface, a planar polar cross section, as is the originating state and none other, meanwhile there are adiabatic surfaces arbitrarily close to this state.
Of course, this construction contradicts at least one formulation of the 3rd law of thermodynamics, namely, the one that states that as $T\to 0$ the specific entropy must approach a constant value, usually expressed as $\lim_{T\to 0} \frac{\partial S}{\partial T}=0$ independently of any other extensive configuration variable it may depend on, $\lim_{T\to 0} S(T,\mathbf x)=S_0(\mathbf x +\Delta \mathbf x).$
Interestingly, in the conventional derivation of the existence of entropy based on Carnot cycles the single or multi-valued nature of entropy does not come up at all, and of ocurse in the alternative axiomatization that is along the lines of Carnot, Gibbs, Bronsted the existence of a single-valued entropy function is just postulated. In Arens's original 2D example there are neither adiabatic or isothermal cycles, but there is always a Carnot cycle that can link any two states of positive temperature$^{[\mathbf 2]}$.
With this background, my question is:

Does Caratheodory's construction need the 3rd law to avoid this
problem of potential multi-valuedness of the entropy function and if
yes then how?


If, in fact, Caratheodory's construction does not need
the 3rd law then how does single-valuedness of the entropy follow from his axiom and mathematics, if at all?


$[1]$ The original example is from Arens: "An Axiomatic Basis for Classical Thermodynamics", https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82563543.pdf, section 5.5; this is a very interesting work but unfortunately its print is full of typos making it a more difficult and confusing read.
$[2]$ throwing a small wrench in the cauldron, Arens comments at the end of 5.5 that

"One might venture to suggest that speculations as to whether there
are remote regions in the universe where the laws of thermodynamics
are violated, ought to be replaced by speculations as to whether there
are cyclic processes, requiring temperature variations too wild for
human engineering to construct, for which $\oint d\sigma$ is not $0$."

